# Binding font icon on masterpage Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I am trying to add fonts in my masterpage using Font Awesome.
here is my code for it

```
new NavMenuItem { Id = 3, Title = "Home", TargetType = typeof(NavDetail), icon = "&#xf015;"}
```

and here is my label code from masterpage`enter code here`

```
<Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"          
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    Text="{Binding icon}"                                   
    Style="{DynamicResource FontLabel}"
    FontSize="24" />
```

The problem is it just prints out the hex value as it is instead of printing the icon. if i simply write Text="" it works but when i try to bind it doesnt work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in [Binding font awesome character in XAML to Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577489/binding-font-awesome-character-in-xaml-to-text), you can achieve it using the unicode format.

You can get the unicode value with your browser:

[image]

And you only need to add an **u** after the slash ('/')

Comment: This was very helpful. See answer on the Xamarin forms forum for explanation on difference between binding in C# vs xml encoding in xaml file: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/136296/bind-html-entity-hex-string-to-show-icons-in-a-label

Answer (score 6):

Try the below

```
icon = ((char)0xf015).ToString();
```

Comment: This!!! If you're using Binding and you'd like to change the icon based on a binding property this is the way to go. Thank you VenkyDhana!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Class from the link: 
https://github.com/fzany/Font-Awesome-Cheat-Charp

```
public class FontAwesome
{
    public static class Solid
    {
        public static string Ad = "\uf641";
        public static string Address_Book = "\uf2b9";
        public static string Address_Card = "\uf2bb";
        public static string Adjust = "\uf042";
        public static string Air_Freshener = "\uf5d0";
        public static string Align_Center = "\uf037";
        public static string Align_Justify = "\uf039";
        public static string Align_Left = "\uf036";
        public static string Align_Right = "\uf038";
        public static string Allergies = "\uf461";
        public static string Ambulance = "\uf0f9";
        public static string American_Sign_Language_Interpreting = "\uf2a3";
        public static string Anchor = "\uf13d";
        public static string Angle_Double_Down = "\uf103";
        public static string Angle_Double_Left = "\uf100";
        public static string Angle_Double_Right = "\uf101";
        public static string Angle_Double_Up = "\uf102";
        public static string Angle_Down = "\uf107";
        public static string Angle_Left = "\uf104";
        public static string Angle_Right = "\uf105";
}
}
```